# Is it true that the polynomial $x^5 + x + 1$ has all its simple roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I know that $a$ is root of $p$ iff $p(a)=p'(a)=0$

$p(x)= x^5 + x + 1$

$p'(x)= 5x^4 + 1$ then $p'(a)=0$ iff $5a^4 + 1 = 0$ iff $a^4=-1/5$

Now, $p(a)= a^5 + a + 1 = a. a^4 + a + 1 = (-1/5) a + a + 1 = (4/5) a + 1 = 0$

then, $a = 1 - 5/4$ so $a = -1/4$. But $(-1/4)^4  ≠ -1/5$ so there is no solution. So $p$ does not have multiple roots.

So $p$ has all its simple roots.

Is my exercise resolution correct? Are the steps well explained and justified?

Comment: Where'd the $a^4$ go?

Comment: I suppose you mean $a$ is a *multiple* root if and only if …

Comment: "... then $a=1-5/4$" is not correct.

Comment: @BadrB I  wrote badly that step. The correct is $a^4=-1/5$. I corrected it.

Comment: From $(4/5)a+1=0$ you should get $a=-5/4$, not $a=-1/4$. But your reasoning is otherwise correct, since $(-5/4)^4\not=-1/5$ either.

Comment: @BarryCipra You're right. I already correct it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ayesca, you corrected "$a=-1/5$" to "$a^4=-1/5$" early in your proof. This is a second mistake, toward the end. Both mistakes are minor, but both warrant correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a minor mistake when you wrote that $5a^4+1=0\iff a=-1/5$. You should have written $a^4=-1/5$ instead.

The rest is correct, assuming that you are working over a field with characteristic $0$.

Comment: You're right, I wrote badly that step. Thank you very much, I corrected it.

Comment: @Ayesca I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, you overlooked a second minor error. See my comment below the OP.

Comment: @BarryCipra You're right: I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x)=x^5+x+1$ and $f'(x)=5x^4+1$ like you said. Since $f'(x)$ is always positive, we can conclude that $f(x)$ is always increasing. This means that the function only crosses the x-axis once (since $f(x)$ is of odd degree). Therefore we can conclude that $f(x)$ has only one real root, and since the function is always increasing, it must be a simple root.

Comment: The OP wants to show that *all* the roots are simple, not just the real roots.

Comment: @BarryCipra Ohh I see. Thanks for the pointing that out.